# Extract word and digit from string using SED

Tags: regex, shell, sed

how can I extract the `TIC-9890` from a
branch name that looks like `feature/TIC-9890/some-other-wording`

---

I am not a SED expert, but I managed to come up with:

```
echo "feature/TIC-000/random-description" |
sed -n 's/.*\(TIC-[0-9]\{1,\}\).*/\1/'
```

This seems to work fine if the `TIC-\d+` string is in there,
but returns the entire string if that is missing...

However, I need it to return null or empty string if the match isn't present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add a `p` option to print and it should fly then. Why because we have stopped printing of `sed` by using `-n` option so when substitution happens then `p` needs to be used to print it.

```
echo "feature/TIC-000/random-description" | sed -n 's/.*\(TIC-[0-9]\{1,\}\).*/\1/p'
```

***From `man sed` page:***

> -n, --quiet, --silent suppress automatic printing of pattern space
>
> p      Print the current pattern space.

---

---

OR as per @anubhava sir's comments one could use `grep` with `-E` option we could try:

```
echo "feature/TIC-000/random-description" | grep -oE 'TIC-[0-9]+'
```